# Facing issue in using Worklight JSON Store

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am new to worklight studio, trying to use JSON Store. Facing error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'exec'

```
var globalPID = [ {
    "start_date" : "\/Date(1341212400000-0700)\/",
    "PID" : "96052",
    "project_name" : "Copy and Print Microsite Implementation"      
}]; 

var searchFields = { PID: 'integer', project_name: 'string' };
var addSearchFields = { Probability : 'integer' };
var options = {onSuccess: win, onFailure: fail};
var pidCollection = WL.JSONStore.initCollection('globalPIDs', searchFields, options);
pidCollection.store(globalPID,options);
```

messages in LogCat:

```
07-19 17:05:32.918: D/CordovaWebView(541): >>> loadUrl(file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/PivMobileNew.html)
07-19 17:05:32.928: D/CordovaWebView(541): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-19 17:05:32.973: D/DroidGap(541): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/PivMobileNew.html)
07-19 17:05:34.348: D/DroidGap(541): onMessage(spinner,stop)
07-19 17:05:41.668: D/CordovaLog(541): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
07-19 17:05:41.668: D/CordovaLog(541): file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/wlclient/js/jsonstore/jsonstore.js: Line 525 : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
07-19 17:05:41.688: E/Web Console(541): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec' at file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/wlclient/js/jsonstore/jsonstore.js:525
07-19 17:05:44.998: E/libEGL(541): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-19 17:05:44.998: D/ShaderProgram(541): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-19 17:05:44.998: E/libEGL(541): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-19 17:05:44.998: D/ShaderProgram(541): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-19 17:05:44.998: E/libEGL(541): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-19 17:05:44.998: D/ShaderProgram(541): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-19 17:05:44.998: E/libEGL(541): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-19 17:05:44.998: D/ShaderProgram(541): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-19 17:05:44.998: E/libEGL(541): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
07-19 17:05:44.998: D/ShaderProgram(541): couldn't load the vertex shader!
07-19 17:05:45.098: D/Cordova(541): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/PivMobileNew.html)
07-19 17:05:45.118: D/DroidGap(541): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-19 17:05:45.118: D/DroidGap(541): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/PivMobileNew.html)
07-19 17:05:45.148: D/CordovaLog(541): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
07-19 17:05:45.148: D/CordovaLog(541): file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/wlclient/js/jsonstore/jsonstore.js: Line 525 : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
07-19 17:05:45.148: E/Web Console(541): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec' at file:///data/data/com.PivMobileNew/files/www/default/wlclient/js/jsonstore/jsonstore.js:525
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call JSONStore code after Cordova is ready (inside or after wlCommonInit has been executed).